# uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Actor::Celluloid (NameError) + Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, sidekiq

I am getting `uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Actor::Celluloid (NameError)` while trying to run cucumber test. This happens after upgrading to version 2.12.0.

```
Rails 3.0.20
Ruby 1.9.3-p194
```

This was causing due to the sidekiq-failure gem. Inorder to resolve it I have to upgrade sidekiq-failure or remove it.